# TYPO3 No TypoScript template found - custom page

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

We're running TYPO3 9.5 with correctly set up Site Configuration. The main domain has multiple subdomains which have their own Site Configuration.

```
domain.com
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.com
sub3.domain.com
```

All these urls point to a different Site Configuration, which works fine. But when a user types `sup1.domain.com` instead of `sub1.domain.com`, "No TypoScript template found!" is shown. Within the Site Configuration "Error Handling", "Show content from page" is set up for error 503.

The configured error page is not showing, but the default "No TypoScript template found!". **How could we show an actual TYPO3 page when a subdomain is entered wrong?**

The 404 page works fine, but only with segments after the actual domain, eg. sub1.domain.com/does-not-exist shows the 404 page, as configured.

Comment: Does each subdomain has an own page entry? If yes, double check TS Template please

Comment: @AMartinNo1 Double check for what exactly?

Comment: Maybe, it would be a better solution to redirect all non-existing domains via .htaccess to an existing one.

Comment: @JulianHofmann What? How could I possibly know when a visitor types the url wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was none-sense. Did not got in the first place that you want to handle invalid subdomains. Thought subdomain is invalid due to missing TS Template. My Bad.

Comment: @Andreas, you can not know the exact wrong URL, but you know which (sub)domains exist. So every other (sub)domain is wrong and could be redirected to an existing one. Sure, you can't redirect misspelled names to their correct variant - but therefore it doesn't matter if it's handled by htaccess or PHP/errorhandling.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted by Julian Hofman you should redirect all 'non-existend' subdomains to your main (sub) domain.
Sure, in this situation you cannot handle typos, but this solution is very fast and error-safe. TYPO3 can only handle "known" (sub)domains.

Redirecting all unknown subdomains can be done via .htaccess (on Apache) or your domain hosting admin-panel .

HTH Henrik